# magento 2 - How to enable extension without upgrade magento

Tags: magento2

I followed some steps for installing extension on magento 2.

1) Upload extension folder to code directory
2) Run following command in CMD:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

When i run this command my theme css and images were removed and set default.

Comment: after this command you have to fire this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Thanks, but i want enable extension without fire any command. it is possible?, like magento 1.9.

Comment: there is no option, at least you have to fire one command. you can refer this link [click here](http://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-install-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

Look in this file

> app/etc/config.php

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array (
    'Magento_Store' => 1,
    'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
    'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport' => 1,
    (...)
    'Magento_WishlistSampleData' => 1,    
  ),
);
```

Add your module to the list, assign '1' to it and clear all enabled caches using

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Assigning '0' to a module disables it also.

I suggest you check the Magento mode: Developer or Default. If you need to set it:

```
magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

More info over here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it available. Because bin/magento setup:upgrade will be call **install script/upgrade script** make sure module stable to work, If you want to do that only 1 way that is updated record in table **setup_module**

Answer (score 0):

After the adding exteion to your store you have to run these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgarde
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```